# Fiware Lab: Context Broker instance disk space

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I have deployed at Fiware Lab an instance of the Context Broker.

The instance has assigned 40GB  but when I execute the command

```
df -h
```

I see the following

```
/dev/vda1 4,8GB
tmpfs 1,9 GB
```

Where are the other GBs?

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a known bug in Orion Instance. --- Please, check this answer which might solve your problem:

[How to extend default partition after creating an VM instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23534248/how-to-extend-default-partition-after-creating-an-vm-instance/23536152#23536152)

Answer (score 1):

You could try `sudo fdisk -l` (or just `fdisk -l` as root user) in order to see if there is space in VM disks but not mounted or partitioned.

Comment: Dear Fermin , I have executed the command and I get this output _[centos@orion ~]$ sudo fdisk -l

Disco /dev/vda: 42.9 GB, 42949672960 bytes
145 heads, 4 sectors/track, 144631 cylinders
Units = cilindros of 580 * 512 = 296960 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000574cf
Disposit. Inicio    Comienzo      Fin      Bloques  Id  Sistema
/dev/vda1   *           4       18075     5240704   83  Linux_ The virtual machine is in use, what can I do now without losing my data and applications. Thanks

Comment: There you have: 42.9 GB ;) Now it is a matter of partitoning and mouting that space. However, I guess that is out of the scope of this question. Please, check basic GNU/Linux management documentation regarding disk management.

Comment: Thanks for your comment

Comment: You're welcome! If you find my answer useful, please provide a +1 vote and acceptance tick. It is not to feed my ego :), it is to show other uses that the answer is correct and useful for them. Thanks!

Comment: I appreciate the comment but it does not give me the solution to the problem. I still need to figure out how to do it and I do not know what data loss risks I may have. I deployed a iamge of Orion Context Broker in FiwareLab with a flavor of 40GB and after 5 days in use I found the disk full and with only 5GB assigned. In the documentation I have not seen any warning about it, if it exists I have not found it, but there is a recommendation that it be included. Anyway I am new at stackoverflow and I dont now how to give you +1 :)